# Parametrize docker-compose image pull

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose yaml that looks like the following:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
    my-service:
        image: xxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/yyyy:latest
```

It pulls the latest image of a docker in ecr. I want to slightly change it to

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
    my-service:
        image: xxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/yyyy:${tag}
```

that is, to be able to pass a `tag` parameter when I do the `build`. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: See [Variable substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution) in the Compose documentation; it should work with exactly the syntax you show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `.env` file in the same directory where your `docker-compose.yaml` is located or you pass it to the cli like `tag=latest docker-compose up`.

Example `.env` file:

`tag=latest`